# Find and replace custom tag

Tags: c#, regex

I have some input string like

```
<Parameters><job>true</job><BeginDate>August2017</BeginDate><processed>true</processed></Parameters>
```

I have to extract `BeginDate` value and replace it with actual datetime value. So output should look like

```
<Parameters><job>true</job><BeginDate>08/01/2017</BeginDate><processed>true</processed></Parameters>
```

I am able to find `August2017` and replace it with actual date but I am having trouble replacing that to the original.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(customDate, @"<BeginDate>([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\<\/BeginDate>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(key, "MMMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    ???? how to replace newDate back to original ????
}
```

Comment: You have XML. Why don't you use something designed to deal with XML instead of treating it as string?

Comment: I only showed partial string. It's not actual XML but string with XML like tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(inputString);
var BeginDate = xDoc.Descendants("BeginDate").First();
BeginDate.Value = "08/08/2017";
var outputString = xDoc.ToString();
```

Comment: It might help the OP if you add a little description, perhaps you can describe why you aren't using regex but the XDocument DOM function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the original format you expected in a replace.

```
customDate = customDate.Replace(newDate.ToString("MMMMyyyy"), newDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Consider another approach to what **appears** to be XML:

```
var xe = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(customDate);
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(xe.Element("BeginDate").Value, "MMMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out var newDate))
{
    xe.Element("BeginDate").Value = newDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

You can then get the string back using:

```
xe.ToString(System.Xml.Linq.SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)
```